Moment generating function of one-side bounded random variable
Suppose we have a scalar random variable $X$ satisfying the one-sided bound $X \leq d$, for some $d > 0$. Additionally, we know that $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq 0$. Can we establish a bound of the following form on the moment generating function of $X$:
$$ \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X)] \leq \exp(c \lambda^2 d^2), \forall \lambda \geq 0, $$
for some universal constant $c$. Such a bound holds when $X$ is mean zero and uniformly bounded in magnitude. I am wondering if a one-sided uniform bound on $X$ along with the fact that $X$ has negative mean suffices to control the M.G.F. of $X$.

No.
E.g., suppose that $P(X=-1/h)=\frac h{1+h}=1-P(X=1)$, where $h>0$. Then $EX=0$ and $X\le1$.
However, $Ee^{hX}=\frac{e^h+h/e}{1+h}=1+h/e+O(h^2)\not\le e^{ch^2}$ for any real $c$ if $h\downarrow0$.
(In fact, here $Ee^{hX}>1+h/e$ for all real $h>0$.)

I presume you are doing a second-order Taylor series expansion of $(\exp(hx))$? In that case, shouldn't the linear term be $hX$, with mean equal to $0$ (instead of $h/e$)?

@user535695 : No, this is not what I am doing. I have added a detail on this.

I see, thanks! I was trying to understand whether one can obtain Azuma-Hoeffding-like inequalities for super-martingales that are only bounded from above. Since the standard proof with double-sided bounds goes through a bound on the moment-generating function (like that in this question), I was interested in knowing whether such a bound exists. Are you aware of such variants of Azuma-Hoeffding (with one-sided bounds on the super-martingale differences)?

@user535695 : To have such bounds, you also need to control the conditional second moments  of the supermartingale differences. See e.g. Theorem 8.2.

Thank you; this is very helpful. I'll take a look at this reference. Do you know whether a control on the conditional second moment is necessary to obtain such a variant of Azuma-Hoeffding?

@user535695 : The example in my answer shows exactly this, that one cannot have the desired bound without having control on the second moment.

@user535695 : Do you have a further response to my answer and comments?
